# Faulty CSS glow effect not working on Safari

Tags: css, wordpress, safari, elementor

I am not a programmer and I really need an opinion.

I added a CSS code to my website for glow effect.

Apparently it breaks on Safari (iPhones).

I was able to pin-point the faulty code to the below lines.

Link: https://www.sepaga.com/

```
/*COLUMNS GLOW*/ 
.glow > .elementor-widget-wrap{
position:relative;
}

.glow > .elementor-widget-wrap:after{
content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0; right:0;
  z-index:-1;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
background: linear-gradient(270deg, #52a54a, #a3db73);
  filter:blur(100px);
  transform:scale(.9);
  background-size:200% 200%; 
  animation: animateGlow 3s ease infinite;
  
}

@keyframes animateGlow{
  0%{ background-position:0% 50%}
  50%{background-position:100% 50%}
  100%{background-position:0% 50%}

}

.glow_btn .elementor-button-link{
animation: animateGlow 3s ease infinite;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, #52a54a, #a3db73);
    background-size:200% 200%; 
  
}
```

Tried removing a few lines but failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution from this guy https://graffino.com/til/CjT2jrcLHP-how-to-fix-filter-blur-performance-issue-in-safari

Apparently there is a workaround for the filter: blur; function to work with Safari

Here is what to add:

```css
    filter: blur(100px);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)!important;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Can I Use [Can I Use Filter](https://caniuse.com/?search=filter) the `Filter` is a know issues on Safari browser. Under know issues :

> In Safari filter won't apply to child elements while they are animating.

You can remove the `Filter` and instead use `backdrop-filter`.

```css
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, #52a54a, #a3db73);
  backdrop-filter: blur(100px);
  transform: scale(.9);
  background-size: 200% 200%;
  animation: animateGlow 3s ease infinite;
```

Comment: Thank you for your insight. When i make that change it breaks the blur. And also backdrop-filter gets marked red (meaning its not working)